# decltype(auto), trailing return type and sfinae: can we mix them?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, sfinae, decltype

Consider the following code:

```
auto f() -> decltype(auto) { /* do whatever you want here */ }
int main() { f(); }
```

The return type is deduced and `decltype(auto)` is used as trailing return type.
The code below is a slightly modified (actually, *sfinae'd*) version:

```
struct S { static void f() {} };
struct T {};

template<typename U>
auto f(int) -> decltype(U::f(), void()) {
    // do whatever you want here
}

template<typename>
auto f(char) -> decltype(auto) {
    // do whatever you want here
}

int main() {
    f<S>(0);
    f<T>(0);
}
```

If you take in exam this function:

```
template<typename U>
auto f(int) -> decltype(U::f(), void()) {
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

The question is: is it possible to use the trailing return type to do sfinae and still have the return type deduced?
I mean something like the code below (that doesn't work, of course):

```
template<typename U>
auto f(int) -> decltype(U::f(), auto) {
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

---

Note: I'm not looking for alternative approaches involving template parameters, I know them and I'm just curious to know if **this** is a viable solution.

Comment: Don't think it is possible but would you want the type to be deduced as `auto` or as `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: Don't think there's anything you can do here. Deduced return types deliberately don't SFINAE.

Comment: @Holt Good question, I would have said `decltype(auto)` as in the first example, but if you know how to have it deduced as `auto` it can be a good answer as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype(auto)` is an inseparable construct (almost as if it were a keyword like `decltype_auto`). Other than that, `auto` cannot be used as a standalone entity inside `decltype(x)`, because that would prevent `x` from being a valid expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another parameter of type `void(*)()` to the function and assign a lambda with trailing return type to it as a default argument so SFINAE can be applied via lambda:

```
template<typename U>
decltype(auto) f(int, void(*)() = []()->decltype(U::f(), void()) {})
{
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a possible workaround using void_t.

At least it's as DRY as what you want to do:

```
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;


struct S { static int f() { return 3; } };
struct P { static int p() { return 4; } };
struct T {};

template<typename U, void_t<decltype(U::f())>* = nullptr >
auto f(int) -> decltype(auto)
{
    // do whatever you want here
    std::cout << "f1\n";
    return U::f();
}

template<typename U, void_t<decltype(U::p())>* = nullptr >
auto f(int) -> decltype(auto)
{
    // do whatever you want here
    std::cout << "f3\n";
    return U::p();
}

template<typename>
auto f(char) -> decltype(auto) {
    std::cout << "f2\n";
    // do whatever you want here
}

int main() {
    std::cout << f<S>(0) << '\n';
    std::cout << f<P>(0) << '\n';
    f<T>(0);
}
```